# Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myModule

Tags: html, angularjs

i trying to display 3 variables in view but getting errors in the console

here the code of script.js

```
var myApp = angular
    .module("myModule",[])
    .controller("myController", function ($scope) {
        var employee = {
            firstName: "Sunil"
            lastName: "Bhatraju"
            gender: "Male"
        };

        $scope.employee = employee;
    });
```

here is the code of demo.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myModule">
<head>
    <script src="Scripts.js/script.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts.js/angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="myController">
<div>
    First Nmae: {{ employee.firstName }}
</div>
<div>
    Last Name : {{ employee.lastName }}
</div>
<div>
    Gender : {{ employee.gender }}
</div>
</div>
```

the errors its displaying on the console are

1)Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

2)Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myModule due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myModule' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

[image: here the image of my webstrom project]

Comment: Do you have a folder by the name of Scripts.js ?

Comment: is this `angular.module("myModule",[])` defined at multiple places

Comment: yes Vivz i will add the screenshot of my webstrom project aswell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple errors

one add commas at the end

```
var employee = {
        firstName: "Sunil",
        lastName: "Bhatraju",
        gender: "Male"
};
```

two add angular lib first

```
<script src="Scripts.js/angular.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts.js/script.js"></script>
```

Comment: @sunilBhatraju please this answer as solved, I'm glad it helped

Answer (score 3):

You need to load angular.js reference and then your script.js

```
<script src="Scripts.js/angular.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts.js/script.js"></script>
```

and your Object should have comma separated across the fields,

```
 var employee = {
                firstName: "Sunil",
                lastName: "Bhatraju",
                gender: "Male"
            };
```

**DEMO**

```js
var myApp = angular
    .module("myModule",[])
    .controller("myController", function ($scope) {
        var employee = {
            firstName: "Sunil",
            lastName: "Bhatraju",
            gender: "Male"
        };

        $scope.employee = employee;
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myModule">
    <div ng-controller="myController">
<div>
    First Nmae: {{ employee.firstName }}
</div>
<div>
    Last Name : {{ employee.lastName }}
</div>
<div>
    Gender : {{ employee.gender }}
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: this didn't solved the issue same error display even after changing it

Comment: check the path of your scripts

Comment: didn't put commas that was the issue... thanks for answering

Comment: my problem was because of not putting the commas so that was answered by Rakeshchand so i put his answer as accepted one

Comment: thats what my answer also says